# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException using 2 iterators

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to iterate through a HashMap using 2 iterators. Firstly for every key(Integer) in the hash I compute "similar" numbers(it really doesn't matter what similar numbers are in this particular case) and then I have to delete the keys which are similar to the current key by making them values of the current key. I keep receiving this exception

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. What could be the cause? Do I have to use a ConcurrentHashMap?

This is the code I am compiling:

```
Set<Node> keySet = hash.keySet();
Iterator<Node> it = keySet.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Node key = it.next();
    ArrayList<Integer> similar = getAppropriateNum(key.getLabel(), 2);
    for(int j = 0; j < similar.size(); j++){
         Iterator<Node> it2 = keySet.iterator();
         while(it2.hasNext()){
             Node nod = it2.next();
             if(nod.getLabel() == similar.get(j) && !nod.equals(key)){
                  it2.remove();
                  hash.put(key, nod);
             }//end if
         }//end while
    }//end for
}//end while
```

Comment: Delete after the loop. Store the values you want to delete in a Collection and once you have exited the loop, delete.

Comment: btw, I don't like the `if(nod.getLabel() ==` part. Prefer `equals()` if possible.

Comment: Sadly, this is a prime example of a misleading exception name. `ConcurrentModificationException` does not refer necessarily to a problem involving concurrency (i.e. multiple threads) and generally means that an iterator has come to have a stale view of the contents of a data structure. Whether this happened because a different thread modified the collection or the same one is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are removing an item using an iterator (good practice) but the other iterator is not aware of that. Hence, the call to `it.next()` fails.

You should try to use only one iterator or remove items after looping.

**EDIT** : After analyzing your question, it seems that your need is to create a Collection of unique items. This makes me think that you would like to use a Set with a well-formed Comparator. In this way, adding all your items to your Set will automatically remove duplicates.